# Support for URLs with GET parameters (query strings) in Expression Engine 2?

Tags: php, html, forms, expressionengine

I'm developing an add-on for Expression Engine that has a search facility.

For search forms in the past, I've used a standard HTML `<form>` with its `method` attribute set to `GET`, and then server-side I'd parse this `GET` variables into some form of `WHERE` condition for a database query.

I'm trying to implement this logic in an Expression Engine add-on, but it seems Expression Engine does not like URLs with query strings, as when I submit the form the page breaks (it throws a 404 error).

Does Expression Engine support URLs with query strings? Or does this break the internal routing?

I should also mention that this add-on is to be implemented on many sites (the number unknown) and I'd like to stay away from making any changes to Expression Engine core files (i.e. PHP scripts) if possible, just in case this is suggested.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I thought I'd add some clarification as to what I'm trying to achieve.

In the past, I've used `$_GET` variables to drive search forms. So I may have a URL like:

> http://example.com/search.php?size=large&color=red&page=1

As you can see, my query string contains name and value pairs as the parameters (including one for `page`) and these would created with a form whose `action` attribute is set to `GET`.

If there are `$_GET` parameters present, then `search.php` would parse this, formulate them into a SQL or XPATH query or whatever; and then return the matching records. The user could then page through these records by updating the `page` parameter that is present in the URL; the query would return just another portion of the result set as the other `GET` parameters would still be in the URL.

I want to achieve the same with an Expression Engine add-on. I want a form that takes the user-submitted criteria and then returns a record set that is pageable. I thought using a query string would be the best option given that it is RESTful and whatnot, but as aforementioned Expression Engine didn't like a query string being present in the URL, treated it as a different URL and threw a 404 error.

How can I create an add-on that generates a form, the submitted user is then used to query a database table, and results returned to the user that can then also be page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems URLs with query strings work if there's more than one parameter in the query string, which seems absolutely backwards.

So `http://example.com/?foo=bar&baz=1` works, but `http://example.com/?foo=bar` does not.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this behaviour. There is no official support for using $_GET directly on the front-end in EE, so you're putting your functionality in the hands of something that could be supported only by accident in a single point release of the CMS. Not wise!

Comment: Well I'm unsure how to do it any other way. Like I say, the data I wish to search is held in their own database tables (they're not entries) and I also need to consider paging.

Comment: You can use additional URL segments for paging. So if you redirect to, say, **/search/my_keywords** (and then have your plugin or module take `{segment_2}` as the query), you can add **/PXX** as a third segment to your next/prev page links, then access that segment to set the `LIMIT` parameter in your MySQL query.

Comment: Is there an online reference/tutorial for accomplishing this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But if you dig around in the native EE search module, you should find some helpful ideas there.

Comment: Expression Engine really is crap.

Comment: I was able to workaround this by opening the config.php file and changing this:  `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';`

Answer (score 5):

Note that while it's not the primary purpose of the addon, [SuperGlobals](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-globals) by BoldMinded lets you access GET and POST variables directly in your templates via `{get:MYVAR}` or `{post:MYVAR}` keywords. It's really handy functionality, and I've used it several times for search results, etc. Used in conjunction with SuperSearch, it's an pretty reasonable way to build searches for EE.

Another addon allowing access to GET and POST vars is [Mo' Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) by Rob Sanchez, which is free. It uses the same `{get:MYVAR}` and `{post:MYVAR}` syntax.

One caveat is that if your host is one of the cheap shared hosts for which you have to force querystrings to get EE to work, then GET params are a bad idea. So make sure you have a decent web host. :)

Answer (score 2):

EE does not support $_GET variables on the front-end, no. Suggestion: submit your form to your module's action URL (http://yoursite.com/index.pjp?ACT=XX), then turn your submitted variable into a segment, and redirect to that.

Comment: How would I handle paging? For example, I'd want the same criteria to persist if a visitor went from page 1 to page 2 of results, and so on.

Comment: Before you get too far into development, consider that there are already two popular and feature-packed search modules for ExpressionEngine – *[Super Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search) and [Low Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search)*. Perhaps one their native features, Extension Hooks or API calls is something you could leverage?

Comment: Records for this module are stored in their own database tables and not Expression Engine's default tables. Would the above still work?